# Equalize DIVs height on the same line without container

Tags: javascript, html, height, inline

I have a list of divs (inline-block) with fixed width 350px and auto height to fit the content.
The divs are displayed inline so it will display :

- 1920px > 5 articles per line
- 1700px > 4
- 1366px > 3 articles.

and so on ...
So i found my self with with different height divs,
My question is is there a way to equalize the height of divs in same line, for example :
Line 1 : highest div is 540px so all divs in same line will be 540px
Line 2 : highest is 480px so all divs in it line will be 480

I know a script which will search for the biggest height and apply it to all divs, but if the biggest height is for example 600 px it will reproduce a big blank in line with lil content divs if it apply it to all.

PS : If possible without a container, because a row must be responsive according to screen width, and without using flex (ok the flex condition is lil bit stupid i admit) .?!!! Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code so we can offer suggestions

Comment: @RolandoYera here it is https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPS8EHD0R21D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new container needs to be added to support the rest of the divs. The divs, on their own, can't figure out where they are in the window with the way you have it. Also, you should read about flex, it's very helpful. Here's the W3 pen you posted but [updated](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPS0WR7IR4R8).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does what i asked for, i know flex would be the solution but as newbie i always delayed flex learning to later, with this example i just understood let say 50% of the BASIS and what it's untended for. i better start learning it

Comment: Flex is something that everyone refers to, meaning, you have to have a "go to" reference, it's really not something one remembers. There's a lot of moving parts with flex. The one problem is, you asked for help, but told everyone not to tell you how to fix it in your postscript. Notice how no one responded to this very easy fix. Try not to limit yourself...

Comment: Here's a great reference that a lot of people refer to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You re right but notice how i just admitted in my question : "ok the flex condition is lil bit stupid i admit", i don't know what made me put this stupid condition, i already started with the guide you supplied, thanks a lot